# How to fetch from deleted branch of closed pull request

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to fetch the branch from this PR: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/43860

I have already cloned the pandas repo.

If I do

```
git remote add nickfillot git@github.com:NickFillot/pandas.git
git fetch nickfillot
git branch -r | grep nickfillot
```

then the branch `patch-2` isn't there.

This isn't too surprising, as it was deleted.

But...is there a way to fetch it anyway, seeing as the pull request was opened?

Comment: If the PR is *still* open, the target repository (the one with the open PR) has a `refs/pull/<number>/head` that you can fetch: `git fetch <name> refs/pull/43860/head:refs/heads/pr-43860` for instance.

Comment: (GitHub will also usually let you fetch by hash ID, but the `https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/43860` translates directly into `refs/pull/43860/head` which is easier.)

Comment: @torek it's not open

Comment: @torek however, your suggestion seems to still work, despite it being closed. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting, I was not sure what happens after closing a PR, I guess they leave the ref in place.